# Can't Mount a not copy protected DVD Video?

Tags: 11.04, mount, dvd, multimedia, automount

I'm trying to mount a DVD video that has no kind of copy protection on it. It plays just fine in Windows and in DVD players. If I insert a regular data DVD it automounts just fine and I can browse it. I've installed regionfree, followed the [RestrictedFormatsPlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) wiki, and fiddled with this thing for hours to no avail.

-- EDIT --

This is the error I get trying to load the dvd stream in mplayer from the CLI

```
manyxcxi@Portland:~$ mplayer dvd://

MPlayer 1.0rc4-4.5.2 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team

mplayer: could not connect to socket

mplayer: No such file or directory

Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing dvd://.

libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.10 for DVD access

libdvdnav:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed

libdvdnav:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed

libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.

Can't open VMG info!

No stream found to handle url dvd://



Exiting... (End of file)
```

**It appears to just be plain not seeing it as a valid disc.**

Comment: Do you know what software was used to create the disk, or is it a commercial DVD?

Comment: please post error when running the dvd. Start dvd player in command line and the post its output eg. 
`$ totem`

Comment: Video DVDs don't actually need to be mounted in order to play them, so maybe the desktop environment doesn't automount them. Have you tried just playing the (unmounted) DVD from the command line with `mplayer dvd://`?

Comment: is mplayer using the right device for access to the DVD? use `mplayer -dvd-device /dev/dvd-device dvd://` where you exchange "dvd-device" with the correct device.

Comment: I assume it is the right device, it works with other dvds. However, what can I do to confirm /dev/dvd IS correct?

Comment: There may be additional new copy protection and DRM on this disk. Stuff that lidbvdcss2 cant handle. Please let us know what other media players have you tried other then mplayer.

Comment: How do you know it has no copy protection
Newer dvds can be using [different copy protection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System)

Comment: Have you tried other players such as totem or vlc. I tried to duplicate your issue but did not have mplayer installed on my 11.04 system. I believe totem superceded mplayer. Try totem and open the dvd from its menus.

Answer (score 1):

mplayer has had problems with libdvdnav, which is what might be giving you problems.

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2009-January/075695.html

You might want to try and compile mplayer with out libdvdnav using

> --disable-libdvdnav

in the ./configure file of the source code.

Or simply try something other then mplayer. vlc, or totem. They are perfectly cable player. Then just select play from dvd options.

In totem
Media > open > navigate to dvd on the right hand pane.

In vlc 
Media > open disc > play
vlc has many more options to select the location of your device or dvd.

Comment: The problem that has been driving me crazy, it's just plain not recognizing the disc. I don't believe it is a problem with mplayer as much as Ubuntu isn't auto mounting the disc and isn't seeing it at all. I pop in a data dvd, a blank dvd-r, and a dvd movie and it picks them all up just fine. I'm at the point where I believe there is something weird going on with this disc but am determined to make it load out of pure spite.

Comment: I am even more interested now. I will sit in a chat room today to see where, I can help @manyxcxi

Comment: I won't have an opportunity to do this today, but I will get in touch to see if we can get together and figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed libdvdcss like it says on that wiki page? you will need to do that in order for DVD playback to work.

Comment: I've followed it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

It may still be a copy protection problem in that the dvd software used to create the dvd has encrypted the dvd with out region locking it. A non region locked dvd can still be encrypted.

[libdvdcss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss), is not included in Ubuntu by default because of licensing issues, a simple google search will give you quite a bit of info.

> sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdcss-dev

To test if this is your problem start a player from the command line eg.

> $ totem

Then open the file or location of your dvd. You should then see the following appear on the command line if every thing is working correctly.

```
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.10 for DVD access  
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.3  
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.10 for DVD access  

..........

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x0000014f
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x000001ce
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x0000d3ac
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x002a221f
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x002a226c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x002a4474
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x002a44c1
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x002a67b0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x002a67fd
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x002b1adc
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x002b1b29
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x002ba5ba
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x002ba607
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x00371b8f
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x00371bdc

..........
```

Comment: It isn't left out due to licensing issues; it is not included because it is illegal in the US.  Possessing or using it is a crime under the DMCA.

Comment: @psusi, your are right. The licensing issues I was referring to are the the ones of the codec's and encryption software. That the hardware companies have encumbered that prevent it being included in a GNU operating system. libdvdcss, is some thing completely different. It is software that cracks that encryption used by the dvds. You are quite correct about the legal issues. The encryption is protected by law and circumventing it is a breach of that law.