# Why will burned video DVDs not mount and why are those DVD's wrongly seen as empty in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, mount, dvd, multimedia

This happens with all self-made DVD's I have. Created those quite some time ago on Windows XP with Nero. My DVD player autostarts the DVDs. Windows 7 also plays/sees the files on the DVDs Commercial DVDs open normally, just as self-made data DVDs (old ones made with Gnomebaker), as do audio CDs and data CDs. 
Later I created these simple DVDs on Vista with Nero and later with Nero for Linux; probably Ubuntu 10 (I think). A few (illegal movies) and most DVDs are music bootlegs. The DVDs are named and have two folders that's all: [empty] AUDIO_TS and [containing files in] VIDEO_TS.

Might this be an UDF issue? And should as I saw somewhere /etc/fstab be edited to include UDF specifically? Installed and reinstalled: libudf0, libudf-dev and udftools among other things. Manually mounting gives the following: `sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /media/joost`

```
output:
mount: blok-apparaat /dev/sr0 is schrijfbeveiligd en wordt als alleen-lezen aangekoppeld
mount: onjuiste bestandssysteemsoort, ongeldige optie, ontbrekende codepagina,
       ontbrekend hulpprogramma, slecht superblok op /dev/sr0, of een andere fout
       Soms staat er nuttige informatie in het systeemlog --
       probeer zoiets als:  dmesg | tail
```

(Quick translation from the Dutch: block device /dev/sr0 is write protected will be mounted as read only. mount: invalid/wrong filesystem, invalid option, missing code page, missing help program, bad superblock /dev/sr0 or other error... Sometimes more info  dmesg | tail:

```
joost@joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 6596.943015] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
[ 6596.943019] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
[ 6596.943023] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (1)
[ 6807.503797] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=256, location=256
[ 6808.545327] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
[ 6808.545360] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
[ 6808.545366] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
[ 6808.545371] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
[ 6808.545375] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
[ 6808.545379] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (1).
```

Because data DVDs and commercial DVDs are opening normally I'm at a loss. Also when I insert a burned video DVD all the time Ubuntu gives the message: `cannot mount blank DVD+RW disc location already mounted`. I can see the DVD now in Nautilus; I can drag files to it to be burned on it. Of course that's not possible; if I add a file and click on burn to disk, Ubuntu states that there is insufficient free space on the DVD. All burned DVDs are finalized. With Mplayer, VLC and Totem I tried to access the files on several DVDs, but I had no luck.

In Synaptic I found Dvdisaster and tried it. And Dvdisaster was the only program that detected something on the two DVDs I tried. It gave the name/title and was scanning, but that took too long and burned video play in standalone dvdplayer and windows. Does Dvdisaster use special libraries?

I tried opening a DVD from the terminal:

```
joost@joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320:~$ mplayer dvd://
MPlayer2 UNKNOWN (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing dvd://.
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.BU.
Can't open VMG info!
No stream found to handle url dvd://

Exiting... (End of file)
```

[Totem in terminal also doesn't work.]

I reinstalled restricted extras and codecs (reinstalled these: ibdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdcss-dev), with `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh` and rebooting but to no avail.

I also tried several of the tips [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186361/dvd-wont-mount-ubuntu-12-04) but no luck.

My regionset output:

```
Current Region Code settings:
RPC Phase: II
type: NONE
vendor resets available: 4
user controlled changes resets available: 5
drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF
```

[Do not see a number, but commercial DVDs play normally.]

Is there something that Nero "does" while burning? I do not think so, because only playback issues with Ubuntu (13.04). Some region-free encryption or something which Nero (also) burned which isn't standard? 
I'm thinking UDF support in 13.04, current kernel? But I haven't got a clue.

These errors are from the system log:

```
[ 8969.688339] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=256, location=256
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729916] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729949] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729955] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729960] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: tag version 0x0000 != 0x0002 || 0x0003, block 0
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729964] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
Aug 12 06:38:47 joost-HP-Compaq-nc6320 kernel: [ 8970.729968] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (1)
```

My issue seems a lot like: [Can't Mount a not copy protected DVD Video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53527/cant-mount-a-not-copy-protected-dvd-video) I just ran into this issue today. But it has been a long time since I played a DVD on my laptop, so perhaps old pre-Raring issue. Anyway, I need some help here, I've been googling and trying for hours.

Many thanks in advance!

**My system info:**

• Ubuntu 13.04
• Gnome (3.6.3 2013-03-18)
• Fallback no Effects
• Kernel: 3.8.0-28-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 26 16:28:49 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
• PC model: HP Compaq 6320 Laptop
• CPU: Dual 1.83 Intel Centrino
• Memory: 4GB (of which Ubuntu can only use 3.2GB)
• Hard drive: 160GB HDD
• DVD DRIVE: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T10N (perhaps relevant?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually comes down to disc media used and how fast you burned the DVD...  Those two factors will result in either a good quality DVD or a bad one which lasts a few months then refuses to read properly...  Also the program you use and it's settings can result in the DVD itself reading ok on one machine and not on another...

Ps. Do you have the SMP kernels install so it will use your full 4gb memory ?

Comment: Kernel version is: 3.8.0-28-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 26 16:28:49 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux [So SMP. Perhaps the PAE kernel should be used/enabled?].

Comment: @karel: I'm having no succes in enabling the PAE kernel and saw that PAE is enabled by default in 13.04 (32bit). This line can be seen in  /boot/config-3.8.0-28: CONFIG_X86_PAE=y And found: "PAE is now the standard for a 32 bit Ubuntu, so there is no need for enabling." here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Comment: You we're right about the quality of the dvds. Your reply made me test more (5 not enough) burned dvd video and most won't mount and seen as blank, but (probably well preserved ones) I can access and play. Still don't understand why even if a dvd is damaged the filesystem can't be seen. Old and worn data dvd show their file structure even if not all files can be opened/used. Next to the dvds also issue with hardware; everything opened on standalone dvd player and windows desktop [with Liteon dvd writer with flashed firmware]

Comment: @Joost I added my reply to your comment to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just a typo error in your question, but I found an error in the command you used for enabling playing encrypted DVDs. When you tried to run the `install-css.sh` installation script you opened the terminal and ran:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh
```

This is incorrect. It should be:

```
sudo chmod +x '/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh'
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

For more detailed information on the previously mentioned command visit the [Ubuntu Documentation Restricted Formats/Playing DVDs wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) and read the section of the wiki titled **Installing libdvdcss**.

With regard to your comment about to the DVDs not playing, even though the file structure of the DVD is detected, this could be a consequence of the laser in the DVD drive wearing out, so that you're not getting a strong enough signal to play a burned DVD, only a commercial one. CD and DVD drives do wear out in the course of time, but they are simple and inexpensive to replace. If you tried attaching an external USB DVD drive or swapping the DVD drive that you have, the DVDs might play just fine.

Comment: Just to be sure I will run it again, but probably a typo.